# Apple watch stuck while updating

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I was updating to watchOS 4 beta 3 and its got stuck at this screen

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem before and solved it by doing a forced restart. To do this simply press and hold both side button and Digital Crown at once until the view changes.